# does free() follow pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, free

I'm sure it doesn't, but maybe there's black magic in it, so here's my question:

If I have a struct like this:

```
struct mystr {
    char * strp,
    unsigned int foo,
};
```

and I allocate memory for it and want to release it later. Do I have to do

```
free(mystr_var->strp);
free(mystr_var);
```

or is the last line enought, does the `free()` function follow the pointers and free them two?

Comment: Possible duplicate : You can find detailed answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590812/c-freeing-structs/13590879#13590879

Comment: Okay, thank you. I think this question is answered as good as possible now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every individually allocated block of memory must be freed individually. `free()` will only free the memory block that the pointer points to and its has no knowledge of what is the content of that memory.

Hence, in your case you are doing it the right way by first freeing the innermost memory allocated in a structure and finally freeing the struct pointer.

If you just do free on the struct pointer, the struct memory gets freed. The memory held by `char* strp`, becomes a memory leak in your program lifetime.

Answer (score 5):

No, free doesn't follow pointers, you need both lines.

I usually write a function like:

```
void freemystr(mystr *mystr_var)
{
    if (mystr_var)
    {
        free(mystr_var->strp);
        mystr_var->strp = NULL;
        free(mystr_var);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't.

It's not magic at all, to the compiler it's just another function call.

Ask youself how you would implement `void free(void *);` in a way that follows pointers, of course without being fooled by being given a binary data block containing *anything*. You can't.

Answer (score 2):

No. It simply frees the block pointed to.

You need to explictly free referenced memory. You need to do this first (i.e. most likely in the opposite direction to how you allocated the memory)

Answer (score 2):

No. `free` won't do recursive free for all members. You have to explicitly free all members for which you have allocated memory.

If you understand how memory is allocated for struct and how free works this won't be a problem.

```
struct mystr {
    char * strp,
    unsigned int foo,
};
```

when you allocated memory using malloc & friends, it only allocates memory for the members. 
In your case one `char*` and one `unsigned int`. Note that it doesn't allocate any memory for storing data in the `char*`. So you have to allocate memory for `strp` again before storing data. Except when you directly assign string literals Or just use the pointer `strp` to point to an existing memory.

**Example:**

**case 1:**

```
struct mystr s;

s.strp = "literals"; // valid, no need to malloc
```

**case 2:**

```
char *p="abc";

s.strp = p; // valid, no need to malloc
```

On all other usages, you must allocate memory for `strp` before storing data into `strp`.

So when you call `free` on the struct variable, it only frees the pointer allocated for `strp` and not the memory which is pointed to by `strp`.
It's simply because `free` has no information about where `strp` points to.

Note that in the above two examples, you don't free `strp` as you didn't allocate any memory there for storing data into `strp`. Simple rule is one free for one `malloc/calloc/realloc`.

Answer (score 0):

C99 says,

The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made available    for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the calloc, malloc, or realloc function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the behavior is undefined.