# How to correctly free a structure returned from a function?

Tags: c, c11

I'm new to C and trying to figure out how to dispose of the structures, references to which are returned from a function.

For example, this is roughly what I want to do.

```
typedef struct test_t{
    char *test_c;
} test_t;

int testFunc(test_t** output){
    test_t* testStruct = malloc(sizeof(testStruct));
    char* buf = malloc(sizeof(char)  * 5);
    strcpy(buf, "test");
    testStruct->test_c = buf;
    *output = testStruct;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    test_t* test;
    testFunc(&test);
    printf("%s\n",test->test_c);
    free(test);
    return 0;
}
```

So in main I get the test struct. After `printf` (assume that there is some code after wards) I no longer need it and want to deallocate it. But how to do it properly? Should I just deallocate test_c explicitly first? But what if it wasn't allocated?

Comment: Before doing `free(test);`, you just do `free(test_c);`. "But what if it wasn't allocated?" - what if `test` isn't allocated? There's general way to identify whether `test->test_c` is "freeable". You need to manage that yourself.

Comment: Also see (possible dup): [does free() follow pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13877546/1275169)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the code doing the allocation is the one responsible for freeing. So the correct way to design a program like this would be to create two files test.h and test.c. In test.c, one function "test_allocate" does the allocation and one function "test_free" does the freeing. The caller is responsible for calling both those functions, but not responsible for knowing the inner workings of the struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A structure can be deallocated just like any other pointer. You however have to ensure that all its allocated members are freed before doing so (failing to do so would most likely result in a memory leak of the members of your structure).

```
typedef struct test_t{
    char *test_c;
} test_t;

int testFunc(test_t** output){
    test_t* testStruct = malloc(sizeof(testStruct));
    char* buf = malloc(sizeof(char)  * 5);
    strcpy(buf, "test");
    testStruct->test_c = buf;
    *output = testStruct;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    test_t* test;
    testFunc(&test);
    printf("%s\n",test->test_c);
    free(test->test_c);
    free(test);
    return 0;
}
```

In case your structure doesn't allocate all of its elements, you can set their pointer to `NULL`, which once passed to `free (3)` would be equivalent to doing nothing.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the part about assigning NULL to a reference to prevent an attempt in deallocation of unallocated pointer. Now it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

> But how to do it properly? Should I just deallocate test_c explicitly first? But what if it wasn't allocated?

Basic rule of thumb: if you write a function that allocates a resource, write a complementary one that deallocates it. So when applied to your example:

```
void testFree(test_t* toFree) {
    free(toFree->test_c);
    free(toFree);
}
```

... and then ...

```
printf("%s\n",test->test_c);
testFree(test);
```

If `testFree` is implemented and exposed along with `testFunc`, the callers don't need to know your implementation details. The functions themselves, being part of the same library, will make sure the invariants are maintained properly. Should you ever switch allocation schemes, no calling code needs to change. You would just modify `testFree` to go along with the new `testFunc` and re-link.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to free the memory you,ve allocated for the char in the struct given that you have initialized it. Otherwise, you'll get an error so before any free instruction you should check whether the pointer that holds the memory position for test_p you're trying to free isn't NULL. Besides, the free instruction should take *test as a parameter instead of test.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I just deallocate test_c explicitly first?

Yes, you have to free `test_c` first, because, if you free `test`, you will lose the reference to `test_c`.

> But what if it wasn't allocated?

As you are returning `int` from `testFunc`, you can use it as a state of the allocation of your structure (although, returning a pointer would be a better idea IMHO):

```
int testFunc(test_t** output){
    test_t* testStruct = malloc(sizeof(testStruct));
    if (testStruct == NULL)
    /* testStruct allocation failure. */
         return -1;
    char* buf = malloc(sizeof(char)  * 5);
    if (buf == NULL) {
    /* buf allocation failure. */
         free(testStruct);
         return -1;
    }
    strcpy(buf, "test");
    testStruct->test_c = buf;
    *output = testStruct;
    return 0;
}
```

After that, you check `testFunc` failure:

```
/* Check for allocation failure. */
if (testFunc(&test) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Allocation error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
/* Allocation succeeded. */
printf("%s\n",test->test_c);
free(test->test_c);
free(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a procedure which allocates and initializes an instance of `test_t`. In C++ or other object-oriented languages this would be a constructor. In C you have to roll your own - something similar to the following:

```
test_t *create_test_t(char *init_test_c)
  {
  test_t *tt;

  tt = malloc(sizeof(test_t));
  if(init_test_c != NULL)
    {
    tt->test_c = malloc(strlen(init_test_c)+1);
    strcpy(tt->test_c, init_test_c);
    }
  else
    tt->test_c = NULL;
  }
```

You'll also want a function to get rid of a `test_t` instance correctly. Something like:

```
void destroy_test_t(test_t *tt, bool static)
  {
  free(tt->test_c);

  if(!static)
    free(tt);
  }
```

The `static` parameter is included to control whether `tt` should or should not be free'd. Obviously you don't want to attempt to free a pointer to a static instance of `test_t`, in which case you'd pass TRUE for `static`. For dynamically-allocated instances of `test_t`, e.g. those created using the `create_test_t` procedure, you'd pass FALSE for `static`.

You then use these functions every time you need to create or destroy a `test_t`.

Best of luck.